# How to obtain AUC-ROC instead of accuracy while cross validation?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm performing classification on a dataset and I'm using cross-validation for modelling. The cross-validation gives accuracy for each fold since the class are imbalances, accuracy is not correct measure. I want to get AUC-ROC instead of accuracy.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some code. If you're talking about `cross_val_score` function from scikit-learn package, this function supports custom [scoring functions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics). `roc_auc_score` is in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cross_val_score` support a large number of scoring options.

The exhaustive list is mentioned [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values).

> ['accuracy', 'recall_samples', 'f1_macro', 'adjusted_rand_score',
>   'recall_weighted', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_macro',
>   'homogeneity_score', 'neg_mean_squared_log_error', 'recall_micro',
>   'f1', 'neg_log_loss', 'roc_auc', 'average_precision', 'f1_weighted',
>   'r2', 'precision_macro', 'explained_variance', 'v_measure_score',
>   'neg_mean_absolute_error', 'completeness_score',
>   'fowlkes_mallows_score', 'f1_micro', 'precision_samples',
>   'mutual_info_score', 'neg_mean_squared_error', 'balanced_accuracy',
>   'neg_median_absolute_error', 'precision_micro',
>   'normalized_mutual_info_score', 'adjusted_mutual_info_score',
>   'precision', 'f1_samples', 'brier_score_loss', 'recall']

Here is an example to showcase how to use `auc_roc`.

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X, y = datasets.load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
>>> model = linear_model.SGDClassifier(max_iter=50, random_state=7)
>>> print(cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5, scoring = 'roc_auc'))  

[0.96382429 0.96996124 0.95573441 0.96646546 0.91113347]
```